# Can I access a document on the open internet from my Visual Force page?

Tags: visualforce, canvas, document

I am wondering if its possible to access documents from outside SalesForce in a VisualForce  page? It is my understanding that to access resources outside of SalesForce I may have to use a Canvas?

Is this correct? From playing around with the Canvas it doesn't look like a viable option to me. My VisualForce  page has to work on an iPhone and the Canvas does is not usable on an iPhone due to a bug in Safari where the iFrame that the Canvas creates cannot scroll.

So as I am relatively new to SalesForce I was wondering if there are standard ways to access documents on the open web from within a VisualForce page without the need for a Canvas that I can look into?

Comment: What do you mean when you say document? Where is the external resource?

Comment: For example a PDF document hosted on my website - http://www.donalrafferty.com/cv.pdf - would it be possible to access this from a VisualForce page either to render it within a VisualForce page or get it to download?

Comment: You want to display the PDF inside of a Visualforce page all in Salesforce1? Does something like this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Canvas. @Daniel Hoechst has pointed you to a good solution to the specific issue you've mentioned that you're dealing with with respect to PDFs.

I highly recommend that you work through the [Salesforce1 App Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide_introduction.htm) and the [Mobile App Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_platform_mobile_services.meta/salesforce_platform_mobile_services/preface_preface.htm). There was an awesome webinar Wednesday where @metadaddy was a co-presenter called *Visualforce in Salesforce1: Optimizing your User Interface for Mobile*. The slides from it are available on [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/visualforce-in-salesforce1-optimizing-your-user-interface-for-mobile) and the video will eventually be available on the [YouTube Salesforce Developers Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/DeveloperForce). The audio from it should also be available soon from [Developer Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/en/events/webinars/Visualforce-in-Salesforce1). I should mention that for mobile there are LOTS of example projects and resources you'll want to look at on Heroku. You'll find many of them referenced in the slide package from the webinar.

It goes without saying that you'll also want to go through the [Visualforce Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/workbook_vf_intro.htm) and get the [Visualforce Developer’s Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm).